# Android DuplicateFileException when using RealmSearchView

Tags: java, android, dependencies, realm

I am trying to implement RealmSearchView ([link here](https://github.com/thorbenprimke/realm-searchview)). But the issue is, when I add it to my dependencies I get the following error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK lib/x86/librealm-jni.so
    File1: C:\Users\Username\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.realm\realm-android\0.82.2\c6325383149a08e5cb668bdc4d3c790708636e47\realm-android-0.82.2.jar
    File2: D:\MyApp\AppName\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\io.realm\realm-android-library\2.2.1\jni
```

My dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.1' 
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

To add Realm I followed their tutorial ([here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started)), and I also followed the RealmSearchView tutorial ([here](https://realm.io/news/android-search-text-view/)) to add that. But they seem to be conflicting?

How can I include both within the project, but without these duplicate files being created?

**EDIT:**
This is what I have added to get it to run:

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/librealm-jni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/librealm-jni.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/mips/librealm-jni.so'
    }
```

However, now I get this error (is it now using the wrong Realm version?)

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method init(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lio/realm/Realm; or its super classes (declaration of 'io.realm.Realm' appears in /data/data/uk.tether.topcom.tether/files/instant-run/dex/slice-realm-android-0.82.2_f252e1b50f018c2840011d6a94a195daa3c99f49-classes.dex)
                                                                                    at uk.abc.def.ghi.RealmUtilities.RealmManagement.intialiseRealmDatabase(RealmManagement.java:20)
                                                                                    at uk.abc.def.ghi.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:63)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

Which breaks the 'init' method call here:

```
public void intialiseRealmDatabase(Context context){
        Realm.init(context);
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Turns out the RealmSearchView version used in the the Realm search controller tutorial ([here](https://realm.io/news/android-search-text-view/)) is out of date. It should be version 0.9.6!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependency to `compile 'com.github.thorbenprimke:realm-searchview:0.9.1'` references Realm version 0.82.2, while you also include Realm 2.1.

You should drop the dependency to `realm-searchview` because it is out of date, or you'll need to copy the repository and update it yourself and manually add it to your project.

Or just update it to a newer version, if it supports the latest Realm versions.

Comment: Yes! I literally changed this just prior to you posting. I realised I was using 0.9.1 whereas I should have been using 0.9.6!

Answer (score 0):

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/librealm-jni.so'

    }
```

use this line in your gradle file will help you.

Comment: The error now shows:

"Duplicate files copied in APK lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so", will I need a pick first for every single one?

Comment: I have added all the pickFirst's required to get the app to run, but now 'Realm.init(context);' is not recognised as an existing method call?

Comment: See the edits for what I have added. It runs, but I now no longer have certain Realm methods